# What is the difference between CreateFile() and CreateFileA()?

Tags: c, visual-studio, serial-port

I am following the tutorial [here](http://xanthium.in/Serial-Port-Programming-using-Win32-API) to communicate with the serial port

The main code to open and then close the serial port is as follows:

```
HANDLE hComm;

hComm = CreateFileA((LPCSTR)"COM8",                //port name
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, //Read/Write
    0,                            // No Sharing
    NULL,                         // No Security
    OPEN_EXISTING,// Open existing port only
    0,               // Non Overlapped I/O              // FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,            // copied from the MFC version
    NULL);        // Null for Comm Devices

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    printf("Error in opening serial port\n");
    printf("err = 0x%x\n", err);
}
else
    printf("opening serial port successful\n");

CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port
```

If I use `CreateFile()` the code compiles fine but the serial port is not opened (I get the `Error in opening serial port` message)

After playing around with the code for a while, I found that `CreateFileA()` opens the serial port successfully (and the only reason I even found this was because when I googled for `CreateFile()` function I was given the MSDN definition page for `CreateFileA()` as the first result

I googled around but I couldn't find what the difference between the two is. I found [this](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=20658), which says I should always `CreateFile()` and the compiler should do the rest, but it didn't work in my case and only works when I specifically use `CreateFileA()`

What is the difference between `CreateFile()` and `CreateFileA()`, and which one should I be using in my program for a basic serial port communication?

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2013 express

Comment: CreateFile is macro which is defined as CreateFileA in ASCII configuration and CreateFileW in Unicode configuration.

Comment: @Alex I found in that old forum post I linked, that we are only supposed to use CreateFile() and the compiler will resolve it to the correct one. What could be the reason it's not working in my case?

Comment: No. Call GetLastError to know the reason.

Comment: I guess your program compiled in Unicode, so with CreateFile and CreateFileW, you need to use `L"COM8"` parameter.

Comment: @Alex GetLastError() shows 2

Comment: Use `_T("COM8"), this should work in both configurations. Read this:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/446/Unicode-MBCS-and-Generic-text-mappings?msg=1420179

Comment: If `GetLastError()` show 2, that's "no such file or directory".

Comment: @AlexF Your comments are doing a great job of answering the question.  Could I ask you to consider consolidating them into an answer.  This is worthy of keeping around, since the whole CreateFile / CreateFileA / CreateFileW / L"String" / "String" / _T("String") issue can be a little confusing to novice programmers.

Answer (score 20):

Some explanation on the windows API is needed here: Microsoft was very early introducing Unicode. Back then, they decided to represent a Unicode character in 16 bits. I guess this was a valid decision at that time. A `wchar_t` on a Microsoft platform therefore is 16 bits wide, (Unicode) text is stored in `wchar_t`s -- this had the advantage that every character had equal width. The drawback is that existing APIs, dealing with `char`, weren't compatible any more.

Nowadays, with 32bit Unicode codepoints, this looks silly -- Unicode text on Microsoft platforms is encoded using UTF-16, so you have both drawbacks: not being compatible with simple `char`-based strings **and** multi-character sequences. On many other platforms, `wchar_t` is 32 bits wide and Unicode is either stored in these `wchar_t`s or encoded as UTF-8 in "normal" `char`s.

But back to the Microsoft API: In order to solve the problem, they renamed all API calls dealing with strings to have an `A` suffixed and introduced a second set of the same calls, taking `wchar_t`, suffixed with `W` for the Unicode variant. Depending on a compile-time switch `UNICODE`, the original names are mapped to the real names with either suffix by the preprocessor.

As you probably know, string literals in C have the type `char *`. To make a string literal of type `wchar_t *`, you need to prefix it with an `L`. In order to automatically do this when `UNICODE` is set, another macro is provided: `_T()`. So what you are expected to do in your code is to wrap any string literal in `_T()`, it will become prefixed with `L` exactly when `UNICODE` is defined.

Therefore, this line:

```
hComm = CreateFileA((LPCSTR)"COM8"
```

should instead read:

```
hComm = CreateFile(_T("COM8")
```

---

A word on `LPCSTR` and `LPWCSTR`: They are nowadays equivalent to just `char *` and `wchar_t *`. So casting is unnecessary. The reason for these names is backwards compatibility to ancient systems with segmented memory and "far pointers". As long as you don't need your code to compile for win16, just forget about them.

---

Finally a personal opinion: Windows knows Unicode for quite a long time (IIRC already with Win95) and it's standard nowadays. It's unlikely you ever want to target a windows system that doesn't support unicode. It's much more likely you want to write some portable code and then the problem is the different handling of Unicode (`wchar_t` on Windows, `char` with UTF-8 on most other systems, UTF-8 is also predominant on the Internet).

To help with that, I prefer to always define `UNICODE`, use `wchar_t` string literals for any constant string needed by the windows API (like your `CreateFile()` call, so just prefix it with `L`) and store all strings internally in `char` using UTF-8, only converting them when you need to pass them to the Windows API. There are two functions for doing the conversion: [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) and [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte). That way, you can easily write adapters for the APIs of other OS's that use UTF-8.