# Unicode filename generated when creating a fileshortcut with IShellLinkA and IPersistFile in Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, shortcut

I have this function to create a file-shortcut in `Win32` :

```
// prototype
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCSTR lpszDesc);
```

When I call it as bellow :

```
StrCpyA(dst_file, argv[2]);
StrCpyA(src_file, argv[4]);

// concat ".lnk" to destination path
StrCatA(dst_file, ".lnk");

HRESULT res = CreateLink(src_file, dst_file, LINK_DESC);
```

It generate the specific short-cut file And then filename is as entered filename in `argv[4]` like this :

```
e.g. : file_shortcut.exe -src 1.bmp -dst 123
```

But the real filename in *file properties* is a unicode name :

```
⸱浢p
```

Even I used `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert dest filename to `WCHAR[]` :

```
INT wch_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, NULL, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, wch_size);
```

In this function I'm used of `IShellLink` and `IPersistFile` interfaces as fllowing :

```
// function implementation
HRESULT CreateLink(LPCSTR lpszPathObj, LPCSTR lpszPathLink, LPCSTR lpszDesc) 
{ 
    HRESULT hres; 
    IShellLinkA* psl; 

    // Get a pointer to the IShellLink interface. It is assumed that CoInitialize
    // has already been called.
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl); 
    if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
    { 
        IPersistFile* ppf;

        // Set the path to the shortcut target and add the description. 
        psl->SetPath(lpszPathObj); 
        psl->SetDescription(lpszDesc); 

        // Query IShellLink for the IPersistFile interface, used for saving the 
        // shortcut in persistent storage. 
        hres = psl->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (LPVOID*)&ppf); 

        if (SUCCEEDED(hres)) 
        { 
            WCHAR wsz[MAX_PATH] = {0}; 

            // Ensure that the string is Unicode.
            INT wch_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, NULL, 0);
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpszPathLink, -1, wsz, wch_size); 

            // Save the link by calling IPersistFile::Save. 
            hres = ppf->Save(wsz, TRUE); 
            ppf->Release(); 
        } 
        psl->Release(); 
    } 
    return hres;
}
```

Any suggested?

Comment: Don't ever call the `A`- (or `W`-)suffixed functions in the Windows API directly, always use the version without suffix that's automatically mapped according to the `UNICODE` macro. Also, wrap string literals used with the windows API in `_T()`.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51462928/2371524) for a bit of background about the windows API and Unicode

Comment: You need to either 1) change `IShellLinkA` to `IShellLink` to match your use of `IID_IShellLink`, and change your `LPCSTR` parameters to `LPCTSTR` to match, or 2) change `IID_IShellLink` to `IID_IShellLinkA` to match your use of `IShellLinkA`. Also, you don't need to call `MultiByteToWideChar()` twice when you already know the max size of your `wchar_t[]` buffer (better, change `lpszPathLink` to `LPCWSTR` and don't call `MultiByteToWideChar()` at all). Also, `argv[]` doesn't use UTF-8, so change `CP_UTF8` to `CP_ACP`

Comment: @FelixPalmen if i want to use (e.g. `StrStrA`) function in console application (that not support to entering unicode filenames), So should not use of `StrStrA`? else when i use of `StrStr` then i should give that a `LPCWSTR` but i have `argv` as `LPCSTR` and in this state i should convert it `LPCWSTR`. because of this I'm using of `A` suffix. Am i right? have you any suggested about this?

Comment: @FelixPalmen actually, it is usually recommended NOT to use the non-suffixed TCHAR versions anymore. There is no good reason for modern code to rely on `TCHAR` anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau sure there is, you avoid exactly this kind of mess resulting from mixing ansi and unicode versions in a wrong way. The IMHO best way is to always define `UNICODE` and use conversion functions where necessary.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: What's the rationale for using the genetic-text mappings as opposed to explicitly calling the Unicode versions?

Comment: Why would a console application not support Unicode names? The console supports Unicode, and the CMD shell has been Unicode since it was ported to Win32 in the early 90s.

Comment: @IInspectable it's just easier not to make mistakes when you don't use any of these suffixes. Of course, consequently always using the Unicode versions works as well.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: The solution here is to use the [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330727.aspx) macro. Using the generic-text mappings is not a solution to any problem I'm aware of.

Comment: @IInspectable sure it does, and it works on older platforms as well. In this example, `IID_IShellLink` obviously mapped to `IID_IShellLinkW`, mixing this with explicitly suffixed functions is asking for problems.

Comment: @eryksun I know dos support unicode. but real dos. but now windows `cmd` not support.

Comment: @FelixPalmen finally which way is better? use of `UNICODE` macro and converting if necessary any where? OR using of `A`, `W` suffixes? But i dont know one thing! if we can use of function with suffix without any coverting, why we should use of function without suffix? is'nt the first way best???

Comment: There's no DOS here. CMD is a Unicode application. It reads input from the command line via wide-character `ReadConsoleW` and executes programs via either `CreateProcessW` or `ShellExecuteExW`. Its use of the legacy console codepage is limited to decoding the contents of batch scripts, reading from the pipe in a `for /f` loop, and (by default without `/u`) redirecting output from internal commands to pipes and disk files.

Comment: @eryksun you are right

Comment: @FelixPalmen _Don't ever call the A- (or W-)suffixed functions in the Windows API directly_ Opinions vary.

Comment: @FelixPalmen someone upvoted my answer but i dont know who down vote it?? it has 1 up and 1 down vote. :(( I need it...

Comment: I didn't vote here...

Comment: @FelixPalmen cant you upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :

Because I defined `IShellLinkA* psl;` interface as `ANSI` And I have to to use of `IID_IShellLinkA` instead of `IID_IShellLink` in bellow function :

```
// mismatch with IShellLinkA
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLink, (LPVOID*)&psl);

// correct way used of IID_IShellLinkA instead of IID_IShellLink
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLinkA, (LPVOID*)&psl);
```

Comment: If the path strings are ANSI, then why were you decoding with `CP_UTF8` instead of `CP_ACP`? Don't pass a UTF-8 string to an ANSI function unless the system locale uses UTF-8 (only the latest Windows 10, but not enabled by default).

Comment: @eryksun Yes, my input filename is not unicode, So should i use of `CP_ACP` instead of `CP_UTF8 `

Comment: Ideally you should be using the `wmain` entry point with Unicode command-line arguments. If you're using `main`, then the native Unicode command line is encoded as ANSI. In that case there's nothing to decode if using [A]NSI functions. But I recommend creating a completely Unicode application if you're not having to deal with cross-platform (Unix) compatibility.

Comment: `CP_ACP` returns the ANSI code for one specific language on the system. This can easily fail. For example directory name can be `L"c:\\English Greek ελληνικά "`, but this has no ANSI equivalent (there is a trick to use ANSI with short filenames but it's too complicated). Use UTF16 everywhere in your Windows program, with `int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])` instead of `main(...)` as suggested. Stay away from ANSI if possible. You can also pass UTF8 to `main`, and then convert to UTF16.