# Issue with CreateFileA method

Tags: c++, winapi

I am having an issue with my application as while reading a file that consists of Unicode characters too. As I am using the `CreateFileA` method to get the data but it doesn't get the Unicode characters properly for which I am facing a lot of issues. Also, I don't know the difference between `CreateFileA` and `CreateFileW`.

I'm sorry I couldn't able to share my code. I will share my that portion of code with you.

```
    HANDLE systemFileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;                                       
    systemFileHandle = CreateFileA(Filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);

    char* inBuffer=new char[totalFileSize+2];
    memset(inBuffer, 0, totalFileSize+2);
    ReadFile(systemFileHandle, inBuffer, totalFileSize, &bytesRead, nullptr);

    And, I am getting the results on inBuffer array be like : Fernw�rmestationSW Au�en.
```

Can't I get it the original way they are?

So can you please help me out with this. It can be very helpful.

Comment: I suggest you start at https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Comment: The difference is that `CreateFileA` expects an ANSI string for the filename and `CreateFileW` expects a wide string. If you're having trouble reading the contents of the file that's a different problem not related to what function you used to open it. Seeing your code and a description of the problem would help.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462048/what-is-the-difference-between-createfile-and-createfilea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462048/what-is-the-difference-between-createfile-and-createfilea)

Comment: You typically should use `CreateFile` instead of calling the raw functions directly. `CreateFile` is a macro that selects `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` based upon the value of `TCHAR`.  This aligns with the type of character used by your project  (i.e. based upon whether Unicode and/or MBCS is specified in the project settings).

Comment: CreateFile(A/W) just opens the file. The difference is between the filename one specifies in ansi or wchar_t. Getting the content is using ReadFile. Unlike iostream it does not do any translation; just getting bytes of disk.

Comment: Yes you are right I am getting the contents using ReadFile but the unicode characters are not coming in the exact way. May be CreateFileA is unable to read them.

Comment: ***May be CreateFileA is unable to read them*** No, that is not the reason. Provided the file is actually opened, the bug is in your reading code. if you specify the wrong file name (because of a cast to the wrong type of string / mixing wide and narrow strings) the file will not be opened.

Comment: Why are you doing this with winapi rather than using c++ streams? You might hope to just call some other function and solve your problems but it won't be that way. You will actually need to spend some time understanding Unicode and text encodings.

Comment: Where is your display code?

Answer (score 0):

`CreateFileA` takes an ANSI-based file name, while `CreateFileW` takes a Unicode-based file name. There's nothing to say about the content of the file, both will return a `HANDLE` to the file where you can then read/write Unicode content as needed.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually my file also includes unicode characters but while getting the data using CreateFileA I think it uses UTF-8 encoding due to which my unicode characters are not coming exactly as present in the file.

Comment: Whether you use `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` has no effect whatsoever on the *content* of the file, only on the *filename* used to create/open the file. It is not like `fopen()` where you can specify a charset that is used during read/write operations on the returned `FILE` structure.  Win32 file I/O doesn't work that way. Once you have a Win32 `HANDLE` to a file, reads/writes on it operate on raw bytes, so it is your responsibility to produce/interpret those bytes as needed.